# Run an executable JAR with external class path

Tags: java, maven, jar, classpath, executable-jar

Using Maven I compiled my project into a JAR that includes all the dependencies except for one big dependecy. The inclusion of the dependecies is done using:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2.1</version>
<configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>com.mypackage.Main</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id> 
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Exclusion of dependencies is done with `<scope>provided</scope>`

The target `myjar.jar` is in the same folder as `BigExternalJar.jar`, but when I try to run:

```
java -cp ".:BigExternalJar.jar:myjar.jar" -jar myjar.jar
```

I get an exception for missing classes (those classes are from `BigExternalJar.jar`).

How can one pack dependencies into a JAR, *using Maven only*, but still be able to add additional JARs in classpath? Note that the `BigExternalJar` is not always in the same folder so I cannot add it manually to the MANIFEST file.

> There are two similar questions that might look duplicate but they do not have an answer to this situation.
>   [Eclipse: How to build an executable jar with external jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502960/eclipse-how-to-build-an-executable-jar-with-external-jar) AND
>   [Running a executable JAR with external dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089779/running-a-executable-jar-with-external-dependencies)

Comment: Don't you use ; to separate class path entries (instead of :)?

Comment: `java -cp ... com.mypackage.Main`. -jar means: ignore -cp, use classpath specified in manifest.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. If so, I conclude from your comment that it is *not* possible to have some dependencies inside a jar then add additional classpath when executing. Correct?

Comment: @JFMeier I think it is ; for windows and : for unix

Comment: Not correct. As I said, just use `java -cp ... com.mypackage.Main`.

Comment: @JBNizet Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you include the big dependency in your jar file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classpath argument is ignored if you use the `-jar` option. Only the classpath provided in the manifest is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- compiler插件, 设定JDK版本 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>xxx.xxx.yourmain</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

pls try this~~~ all external jar will be in your packaged jar